# Moving image with touch events 

Tags: android, image, bitmap, xamarin.android

I need a sample code for when we move(touch) a image from left to right and right to left. Please help me.

Regards,
chakri

Comment: and, What have you tried for same ?

Comment: Learn how to implement ViewFlipper with gesture Detection..

Comment: I am first time developing a game, I dont know how it works So with a sample code I can easily understand exatly. That's why I am asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this code...

**this is your main activity class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int eid = event.getAction();
                switch (eid) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
                    int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                    int y = (int) event.getRawY();
                    mParams.leftMargin = x-50;
                    mParams.topMargin = y-50;
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(mParams);


                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }




}
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="126dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its working fine. But while drag image it ll be away from my cursr point how to solve this @Mehul