# How do I get a view position relative to another view in Android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view

I'm making a app for Android that shows a camera image (after going through some manipulation) on screen using an ImageView and I want to allow to move other ImageViews on the screen - but only inside the the parent ImageView.

Also, I need to get the coordinates of the child views relative to the coordinates of the parent ImageView. i.e - So that (0,0) will not be the whole screen, but the ImageView that shows the camera.

Is that possible at all? If so - How?

Help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: The co-ordinates will be always based on the ParentView

Comment: But it is impossible to put an ImageView inside an ImageView - thus I can't get the relative coordinates?

Comment: What you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to get the relative position of an ImageView to another ImageView

Comment: I think you need to put the imageview in a RelativeLayout if that is possible for your app

Comment: Just tried that - didn't work :/ Still relative to the window

Comment: if you find the positions of the views, relative to its parent, you can calculate the difference Very easily. And hence, the position of an image view, relative to another image view.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move the views by drag here's a lot of info around, e.g [Moving image with touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790477/moving-image-with-touch-events) .

What about getting the top and left side of `minorView` relative to `majorView` it's also straightforward with some plain substraction `minorViewRelativeTop = minorViewTop - majorViewTop`. Use [View.getLocationInWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow%28int%5B%5D%29) for getting these absolute positions.

N.B. That `View.getLocationInWindow()` will usually not work just inside `Activity.onCreate()` so better call it after some delay. For testing it could be sth like:

```
majorView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int[] location = new int[2];
                majorView.getLocationInWindow(location);
                int majorViewLeft = location[0];
                int majorViewTop = location[1];
            }
        }, 1000);
```